# Лікнеп чи лікбез?

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм

Нерідко зустрічаю в україномовних текстах вживання слова *лікбез*.

З одного боку, є радянське російське слово *ликбез* = *ликвидация безграмотности*, є прямий радянський український відповідник [*лікнеп*](http://sum.in.ua/s/liknep) = *ліквідація неписьменності*, тож *лікбез* в українській має бути калькою (що непрямо підтверджується [відсутністю](http://sum.in.ua/s/likbez) такого слова у радянських словниках).

З іншого боку, слово *безграмотність* словниками фіксується ([СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezghramotnistj), [Вікісловник](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)), і словотвір мав би дозволити існування *лікбезу*.

То чи можна вважати слово *лікбез* літературним і вживати його? Які аргументи на користь *лікнепу*?

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR: *Неписьменність* — невміння читати та писати взагалі; *неграмотність* — невміння відповідати нормам літературної мови. Тому у даному контексті правильно — *лікнеп*.

---

Власне кажучи, це запитання радше стосується російської мови, ніж української. Можна навіть стверджувати, що проблема втрати тонких змістових значень є актуальною для всіх видів штучно утворених канцеляритів. :-)

У даному випадку, є два значеннєвих відтінки:

- [*письменність*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pysjmennistj) — здатність читати і писати взагалі (розглядайте це як бінарну характеристику виду **«так|ні»**);

  - а також [*грамота*](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) (явище, а не предмет) ([СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghramota));

    > *Неписьменний час минув — кожний грамоту здобув*
- [*грамотність*](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) — здатність використовувати мову, мовні інструменти, причому не лише письмові, а і усні (кількісна характеристика виду **«погано | середньо | добре | відмінно»**)

Коли створювалася мова наших сусідів, цей аспект не було враховано, і зʼявилося [*грамотность*](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Цитата (<sub>рос.</sub>):

> 1. **умение** читать и писать;
> 2. отсутствие грамматических и стилистических ошибок, соответствие **нормам литературного языка**;
> 3. перен. **владение необходимыми знаниями**, сведениями в какой-либо области.

І, відповідно, <sub>рос.</sub> «безграмотность» могло нести будь-яке із вищенаведених значень.

<sub>рос.</sub> *Ликбез* — так називалася державна програма совєцького режиму по наданню населенню **здатності читати і писати**. Тобто, ліквідація саме *неписьменності*, а не *неграмотності*. Відповідно, у цьому контексті варто вживати **лікнеп**.