# Писемність та письменність?

Tags: значення-слів, синоніми, пароніми

На сайті [української мови](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu) ці два слова знаходяться в розділі пароніми, однак в Академічному тлумачному словнику української мови пише, що "письменність" може мати те саме значення, що і "писемність". Отож, чи справді ми можемо вживати "письменність" у значенні "система графічних знаків, які вживають для писання в якійсь мові або групі мов; сукупність давніх писемних пам'яток якоїсь мови"? Чи ці слова все ж таки мають різні значення?

Comment: Related: [Лікнеп чи лікбез?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2796/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ви влучно зауважили щодо різниці між цими поняттями.
Багато джерел вважає, що вони різні.

Наприклад, Борис Антоненко-Давидович у "Як ми говоримо" має таку думку:

> "Певно, через звукову подібність слів письменність і писемність автори й промовці інколи помиляються, ставлячи одне слово замість другого, як у фразі: «Наша країна визначається абсолютною писемністю», — де треба було поставити слово письменність.
>
> Слово писемність — це позначання слів відповідними графічними знаками — письменами: «Ще задовго до виникнення писемності східнослов’янські племена створили велику та різноманітну усну поезію» («Історія української літератури»). Письменність — це вміння людини передати на письмі свою думку й читати написане: «Колгоспне село — село суцільної письменності» (Остап Вишня)."

Також знайшла статтю з цього приводу у "Складних випадках українського слововживання" Є.Д.Чак:

> "Письменність означає вміння читати й писати. «Сьогоднішня Туркменія – республіка суцільної письменності» («Радянська Україна»). «…Всі люди, що жили в їй [Костівці], мали такий погляд на книжку та на письменність, мов би то річ зовсім не цьогосвітна» (Б. Грінченко).
>
> Писемність виступає в двох значеннях. Насамперед – це система графічних знаків, що їх вживають для писання в якійсь мові або групі мов. «Усі відкриті в Софійському соборі графіті написані кирилівськими літерами – шрифтом, який покладений в основу сучасної російської, української та білоруської писемності» («Радянська Україна»). «П’ятий міжнародний конгрес славістів був особливо урочистим, бо його робота збіглася із святкуванням 1100-річчя створення слов’янської писемності і підготовкою до наступного 150-річчя з дня народження Т. Г. Шевченка – геніального діяча слов’янської культури» («Народна творчість та етнографія»).
>
> Друге значення слова писемність – «сукупність давніх, писемних пам’яток якоїсь мови». «Високий ступінь економічного, політичного та культурного розвитку Київської Русі, а також деякою мірою прийняття християнства сприяли розвиткові писемності. З’явилися перші книги, переважно богослужебні, необхідні для церковних відправлень» (Історія української літератури). «Інтермедії Якуба Гаватовича належать до визначних пам’яток давньої української писемності» («Радянське літературознавство»). «Давньоруська культура – яскраве самобутнє і багатогранне явище. До якої б сторони її не звернутися – чи до писемності (художня література, історія, публіцистика), чи до мистецтва… – скрізь стародавня Русь залишила свій… глибокий слід» (Нариси стародавньої історії Української РСР).
>
> Не можна погодитися з визначенням семантики деяких слів розглядуваного гнізда у ряді сучасних словників. У шеститомному Українсько-російському словнику АН УРСР (т. III, стор. 347) зазначається, що одним із значень слова письменність є «система графічних знаків», і, навпаки, при слові писемність, де саме слід було говорити про систему графічних знаків, нічого про це не сказано. Неточність у тлумаченні слова писемність іде від однотомного Російсько-українського словника 1948 р., відбита в Російсько-українському словнику для середньої школи Д. І. Ганича і І. С. Олійника і в однотомному Українсько-російському АН УРСР.
>
> Цілком правильне тлумачення поняття писемність подане в УРЕ (т. 11, стор. 144).
>
> Отже, *письменність* – це вміння писати й читати; *писемність* – система графічних знаків, що вживаються для писання в якійсь мові або групі мов, і – друге значення – давні писемні пам’ятки."

**З цього можна зробити висновок, що ці два поняття не є тотожними. Можливо СУМ-20 більш точно розтлумачить нам визначення обох цих слів.**